# Grouping CSS @keyframes rules

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-animations

I completely understand that you **cannot** group animation keyframes selectors such as

```
@keyframes,
@-moz-keyframes,
@-webkit-keyframes { /*do something*/ }
```

and that you absolutely **MUST** do

```
@keyframes { /*do something*/ }
@-moz-keyframes { /*do something*/ }
@-webkit-keyframes { /*do something*/ }
```

I know there are pre-processors that can do all this for me. But I am more interested in the reason behind **why** this is the case?

My google-fu is failing me. It seems to always direct me to a stackoverflow page telling someone they 'cannot' do it and they must separate them all out, or telling people about the pre-processors -or- I get sent to that horrible about.com and read stuff like

- [Any Selector Can be Grouped](http://webdesign.about.com/od/cssselectors/qt/tipcssgroupsele.htm) ~about.com

Which obviously is not true in this case. If someone can direct me to an article, or explain to me **why** it cannot be grouped it would be most helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that at-rules and selectors are completely different things.

At-rules are covered in [this section of CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#at-rules), which says that an at-rule consists of exactly one at-keyword followed by some statement (be it a semicolon-terminated statement, or a block). As far as the CSS parser is concerned, what you have is a set of three separate at-rules, one prefix for each vendor and one unprefixed rule for the standard.

The more appropriate counterpart to at-rules would be rule sets, or style rules, described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets). A rule set consists of a selector and a declaration block (containing style declarations). This is analogous to the contents of an at-rule as described above. It also means that the selector is just *one part* of a rule set.

Certain at-rules do allow comma-separated values in their preludes, such as `@media`:

```
@media screen, projection {
    /* Styles for both screen and projection media */
}
```

But instead of grouping the at-rules in entirety, the grouping happens within the value that comes after the at-keyword in the beginning of the rule.

This `@media` rule can be expanded into two separate rules like so:

```
@media screen {
    /* Styles for screen media */
}

@media projection {
    /* Styles for projection media */
}
```

Notice that each rule has its own `@media` at-keyword.

Similarly, when you group multiple selectors into a single rule, what you have is *one style rule*. The part that is grouped is the selector; everything in the declaration block that follows applies to all the selectors that are listed in the group:

```
.foo, .bar {
    /* Styles that apply to both .foo and .bar elements */
}
```

And when you expand it, it becomes two rule sets:

```
.foo {
    /* Styles that apply to .foo elements */
}

.bar {
    /* Styles that apply to .bar elements */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of

> When a user agent cannot parse the selector (i.e., it is not valid CSS 2.1), it must ignore the selector and the following declaration block (if any) as well.

found at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets

---

So each vendor prefix makes the whole rule un-parseable for all the other vendors.

Comment: At-rules are not rule sets either.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli even though this may not be the correct answer for this, I did learn that the whole group must parse for it to be used. Something that may help in the future, so I have given you a **UP** arrow for this.