# Mixing @supports and @media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I'd like to apply a series of styles to browsers that meet two criteria:

1. Are not Internet Explorer.
2. Are a minimum of 1400px.

Individually I can handle each:

```
@supports(not (-ms-high-contrast:active))
@media(min-width: 1400px)
```

I'd like to do something like this though:

```
@media(min-width: 1400px) and @supports(not(-ms-high-contrast:active))
```

Does CSS allow for this in some way?

I've noticed that this can be done by [nesting directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438009/nesting-css-supports-and-media-queries), but I'm hoping to find a cleaner and more readable solution.

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate of that question, but for your purposes it doesn't matter how you nest them since you only intend to apply styles when *both* conditions match.

Comment: I saw the question about nesting but was hoping do avoid doing that. I don't feel that it's a duplicate for that reason.

Comment: You'll have to nest them as that's how the CSS grammar works, but I can reopen your question and post that as an answer.

Comment: I'd appreciate that just in case anyone else has ideas on a clean solution to this problem. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: There’s nothing unclean about nesting them. (There *is* something unclean about detecting IE.)

Comment: You got me with testing for IE not being clean, but that doesn't mean I have to keep doing what I see as sloppy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At-rules such as `@media`, `@supports` and `@keyframes` are separate rules that [cannot be grouped together by their at-keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780495/grouping-css-keyframes-rules/22780689#22780689). That is, it's not possible to write a single rule with a single pair of curly braces that combines two different at-keywords as you are trying to do. So, unfortunately, nesting is your only option here.

The best you can do is write both statements — and their opening/closing braces — on the same lines:

```
@supports not (-ms-high-contrast: active) { @media (min-width: 1400px) {
}}
```

This is basically nesting them as shown in the linked question, minus the excess line breaks and indentation.